# how to save/parse a web page from a hidden frame, in Google app engine for java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, frame

I want to save/parse a web page from a specific frame that is hidden... The frame contains response to a web form submission, and I want to save it/parse through it using code from my web app... I want to do all this in a JSP/Java web app...

Any pointers in this regard will be appreciated :)

Comment: You've asked 3 questions in the last 5 minutes which are all basically variations on the exact same thing. It would be easier for people to help you if you could instead just merge everything into one question with a bit more details on what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to submit multiple forms simultaneously and then hide respective responses(and parse through responses in code) in a jsp/java web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121566/how-to-submit-multiple-forms-simultaneously-and-then-hide-respective-responsesan)

Answer (score 0):

If the hidden frames (iframes?) are results from posts to websites outside your own (external sites), then it can't be done. The cross-site restrictions (same origin policy) in browsers prevents you from accessing anything in frames loaded from other domains from the "parent" frame.

Comment: Is the restriction applicable even if I have created those frames myself (the frames which are hidden)? Basically I want to submit same/similar data to many web forms, and then check response of each submission... For this purpose I am creating a single jsp which will contain multiple forms that submit to respective 3rd party sites-- I plan to assign target frames for each of the forms so that response from each site can be tracked...

Comment: The issue is not who created the iframe, but what the domain of the page in the iframe is. If you were able to read data out of a cross-site iframe, you could use it to read someone's email, to take an example at random